# remote desktop xrdp lots of passwords

Tags: password, xrdp

I'm running ubuntu 20.04 in hyper-v on windows 10.

when I connect to the ubuntu with remote desktop (xrdp server) it asks for lots of passwords (at login, each time I do something e.t.c.)

Because it runs inside my windows 10 those passwords are not needed.

How do I disable "uac" for remote desktop in ubuntu xrdp. When I connect with virtual machine connection or vnc I'm not asked for all those passwords.

BTW: The reason I use rdp is that the desktop size can then be changed.

Best regards
Eigil

Comment: It's damn annoying that it asks you 3 times for your password every single time you want to use RDP after closing your laptop.

Answer (score -1):

There is a free xRDP installation script at https://www.c-nergy.be/products.html

`--sound` option is required to redirect sound. Use `--help` to see other options.

Comment: you can take a look at http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=18725. This has sound installation instruction. It worked with ubuntu 20.04 lts and ubuntu 22.04 lts for me.